Trying to implement Google login on my django-restframework - Vue app but keep getting redirect_uri_mismatch
Title is self explanatory. I have tried every which way to take a crack at this, but kept getting the same error, no matter what I tried for days. Troubleshooting has been difficult due to me not being able to check exactly what redirect_uri string is being passed to the google's endpoint.
I figured I would ask here in the hopes that someone else had a similar issue and figured it out.
Vue-side:

using vue3GoogleLogin
main.ts:

import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'

...

const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_VUE_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {clientId: clientId});


SignIn.vue:

...
      <GoogleLogin :callback="callback">
        <button class="btn btn-flex flex-center btn-light btn-lg w-100 mb-5">
            <img
              alt="Logo"
              :src="getAssetPath('media/svg/brand-logos/google-icon.svg')"
              class="h-20px me-3"
            />
            Continue with Google
        </button>
      </GoogleLogin>

...

    const callback = (response) => {
    // This callback will be triggered when the user selects or login to
    // his Google account from the popup
    console.log("Handle the response", response);
    // const googleUser = decodeCredential(response.credential);
    // console.log(googleUser);
    const jwtToken = axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/dj-rest-auth/google/',{
      code: response.code
    });
     console.log(jwtToken);


    }
    
    return {
      onSubmitLogin,
      login,
      submitButton,
      getAssetPath,
      callback
    };
  },
});
</script>


console.log(response.code) shows the Authorization code that is returned by google.
Django-side:

using allauth, dj-rest-auth among others
Google settings (client_id, secret) are not present in the settings.py, but rather in the DB.

url.py:
urlpatterns = [
...
    path("dj-rest-auth/google/", GoogleLogin.as_view(), name="google_login"),
...
]

views.py:

class GoogleLogin(
    SocialLoginView
):  # if you want to use Authorization Code Grant, use this
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/google/login/callback/"
    client_class = OAuth2Client

package versions:

dj-rest-auth==6.0.0

django-allauth==0.61.1 -> using the most recent django-allauth causes error with dj-rest-auth

djangorestframework==3.15.2

djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.3.1


"vue3-google-login": "^2.0.26",


I am testing locally. I have not tried testing this with servers and proper domains.

I tried to keep the code blocks concise, omitting imports and other codes.

My understanding is, I do not need to add the callback_url to the urlpatterns in url.py, or set up a view for this?

The url http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/google/login/callback/ is already registered on cloud console. I have checked it multiple times.

http://127.0.0.1:8080 (vue), http://127.0.0.1:8080 (django) are both added to the Authorized JavaScript origins.


I tried tracking down where the url is ending up, down to:
backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/client.py
    def get_access_token(self, code, pkce_code_verifier=None):
        data = {
            "redirect_uri": self.callback_url,
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": code,
        }
        if self.basic_auth:
            auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(self.consumer_key, self.consumer_secret)
        else:
            auth = None
            data.update(
                {
                    "client_id": self.consumer_key,
                    "client_secret": self.consumer_secret,
                }
            )
        params = None
        self._strip_empty_keys(data)
        url = self.access_token_url
        print(data)
        if self.access_token_method == "GET":
            params = data
            data = None
        if data and pkce_code_verifier:
            data["code_verifier"] = pkce_code_verifier
        # TODO: Proper exception handling)
        resp = (
            get_adapter()
            .get_requests_session()
            .request(
                self.access_token_method,
                url,
                params=params,
                data=data,
                headers=self.headers,
                auth=auth,
            )
        )

        access_token = None
        if resp.status_code in [200, 201]:
            # Weibo sends json via 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
            if (
                resp.headers["content-type"].split(";")[0] == "application/json"
                or resp.text[:2] == '{"'
            ):
                access_token = resp.json()
            else:
                access_token = dict(parse_qsl(resp.text))
        if not access_token or "access_token" not in access_token:
            raise OAuth2Error("Error retrieving access token: %s" % resp.content)
        return access_token



Where I can verify that the redirect_uri is being passed correctly as request body to a post request.
These are most of the major points. This has caused me a lot of headache, and I am sure to provide any other details necessary to try to tackle this.
